# Update constant in if block and extract it as a field in the same GENERATE statement

Tags: if-statement, apache-pig, constants, extract

I have a relation as below loaded into "calls".

```
(Header India)
(Call1)
(Call2)
(END)
(Header NZ)
(Call1)
(Call2)
(END)
```

I am trying to update the relation so that it becomes as below and I can group by the 2nd field to get country wise call counts.

```
(Header India, Header India)
(Call1, Header India)
(Call2, Header India)
(END, Header India)
(Header NZ, Header NZ)
(Call1, Header NZ )
(Call2, Header NZ)
(END, Header NZ)
```

The first tuple will always be (Header ). I am using the below code where I want to update the constant and then extract that constant as 2nd field. But it is not working. Any suggestions?

```
%declare HeaderText 'Header '
calls = LOAD 'Data File';
extrctd = FOREACH calls GENERATE $0 as (country:chararray), (SUBSTRING($0,1,7)=='Header '?'$HeaderText'=$0:'$HeaderText') as (txt:chararray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is you can write your own UDF to solve this problem. sample code below

**input.txt**

```
Header India
Call1
Call2
END
Header NZ
Call1
Call2
END
```

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER mycountry.jar;

calls = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (line:chararray);
extrctd = FOREACH calls GENERATE $0 AS country, mypackage.COUNTRY(line,'Header') as txt;
DUMP extrctd;
```

**Output:**

```
(Header India,Header India)
(Call1,Header India)
(Call2,Header India)
(END,Header India)
(Header NZ,Header NZ)
(Call1,Header NZ)
(Call2,Header NZ)
(END,Header NZ)
```

**Sample UDF code:** The below java class (**COUNTRY and MyGlobal**) is compiled and generated as `mycountry.jar`

**COUNTRY.java**

```
   package mypackage;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
    import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
    import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

    class MyGlobal {
        public static String myCountry;
    }

    public class COUNTRY extends EvalFunc<String> {
    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple arg0) throws IOException {
            try
            {
                    String input = ((String) arg0.get(0));
                    String header = ((String) arg0.get(1));
                    String output;


                   if(input.startsWith(header))
                    {
                            output = input;
                            MyGlobal.myCountry = output;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            output = MyGlobal.myCountry;
                    }
                    return output;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new IOException("Caught exception while processing the input row ", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks SJ - that worked. However, I have a new question now. In the UDF we are looking for a hard-coded value, i.e. "Header". Is there some way to pass this as a parameter from the calling pig script? Can the EvalFunc be made to accept multiple parameters?

Comment: Yes, you can, you just pass this parameter as second parameter in the caller of pig script and parse it in the UDF code . I have modified the above pig script and java code , please check it.